# Color changes when selected as opposed to when hovered over

Tags: html, css

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  left: 589px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.subtitle {
  position: relative;
  right: 26px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #6b6b6b;
  text-shadow: 0px 0 #6b6b6b, 0 0px #6b6b6b, 2px 0 #6b6b6b, 0 0px #6b6b6b;
}


/* Menu*/

nav {
  position: relative;
  left: 210px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  background: #dc67e9;
  width: 1000px;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 17%;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Coiny', cursive;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 20px
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.bannerimage {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.banner {
  margin-top: 4px;
  background-color: #dc67e9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 589px;
}

.bannerpromo1 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 500px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  color: black;
  text-shadow: -3px 0 white, 0 3px white, 3px 0 white, 0 -3px white;
  font-size: 70px;
}

.bannerpromo2 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 470px;
  margin-left: -780px;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  color: #585656;
  text-shadow: -3px 0 white, 0 3px white, 3px 0 white, 0 -3px white;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.subscribebanner {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #dc67e9;
  position: relative;
  left: 190px;
  bottom: 430px;
  border: 4px solid white;
}

.subscribebannertext {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-family: 'Coiny', cursive;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.howitworks {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  text-shadow: #a8a8a8 4px 6px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 555px;
}

.subheaderbox1 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  right: 315px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #adcae1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.subheaderbox2 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 65px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #adcae1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.subheaderbox3 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 200px;
  left: 450px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #adcae1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.subheaders {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 275px;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: -265px;
  word-spacing: 250px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: white;
}

.box1 {
  position: relative;
  right: 370px;
  bottom: 225px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 5px dotted #dc67e9;
}

.box2 {
  position: relative;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: 500px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 5px dotted #dc67e9;
}

.box3 {
  position: relative;
  right: -405px;
  bottom: 780px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 5px dotted #dc67e9;
}

.step1 {
  position: relative;
  right: 932px;
  bottom: 219px;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.step2 {
  position: relative;
  right: 546px;
  bottom: 493px;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.step3 {
  position: relative;
  right: 153px;
  bottom: 766px;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.section1 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  bottom: 660px;
  background-color: #adcae1;
  margin-left: -570px;
  width: 720px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.section2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 149px;
  bottom: 660px;
  background-color: #adcae1;
  width: 720px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.section1title {
  padding-top: 80px;
  font-size: 70px;
}

.section1text {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

.section2title {
  padding-top: 100px;
  font-size: 70px;
}

.section2text {
  font-size: 35px;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  padding-left: 1px;
}

.imgsect1 {
  margin-left: 148px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1660px
}

.imgsect2 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1668px;
  right: 571px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SweetVie-Home-Page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexstyle.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Shade|Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coiny" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexstyle.css">
    <style>
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="topfiller"></div>

    <div class="header">
      <img src="images/logo.jpg" height="90" alt="SweetVieLogo">
      <h2 class="subtitle">Vegan Baking Made Easy</h2>
    </div>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">COMMUNITY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SUBSCRIBE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="banner">
      <img class="bannerimage" src="images/mainpageimage.jpg" width="1414px" height="580px" alt="homepagebanner">
      <h2 class="bannerpromo1">Premium Packaged <br>Dessert Baking Kits</h2>
      <h2 class="bannerpromo2">High-quality,<br> organic and<br> vegan ingredients </h2>
      <div class="subscribebanner">
        <h3 class="subscribebannertext"> <a href="Subscribe.html" style="color: white"> SUBSCRIBE</a></h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="howitworks">
      <h1>How It Works</h1>
      <div class="subheaderbox1"></div>
      <div class="subheaderbox2"></div>
      <div class="subheaderbox3"></div>
      <div class="subheaders">
        <h2>Click Prepare Enjoy</h2>
      </div>

      <div>
        <img class="box1" src="images/howitworks1.jpg" height="200" width="300" alt="step1">
      </div>
      <h3 class="step1">Select one of the three<br>subscription options</h3>
      <div>
        <img class="box2" src="images/howitworks2.jpg" height="200" width="300" alt="step2">
      </div>
      <h3 class="step2">Get involved and play<br>with your food</h3>
      <div>
        <img class="box3" src="images/howitworks3.jpg" height="200" width="300" alt="step3">
      </div>
      <h3 class="step3">Share or indulge in your<br>decadent and delicious treat</h3>

    <div class="section1">
      <h2 class="section1title">Food Time<br> Family Time</h2>
      <br>
      <p class="section1text">Timeless family fun,<br> sharing special treats with the <br> special people you love </p>
    </div>
    <div class="section2">
      <h2 class="section2title">The Next Step</h2>
      <br>
      <p class="section2text">Health and desserts don't really<br> go together, with the exception of<br> SweetVie's sweets. Vegan desserts are the<br> baby steps you need for the best kind<br> of progress</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgsect1">
      <img src="images/homepagesection1.jpg" width="720px" height="500px" alt="Food Time Family Time.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="imgsect2">
      <img src="images/homepagesection2.jpg" width="720px" height="500px" alt="The Next Step.jpg">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm currently making a website for a school project that requires a menu bar. The menu bar changed to black whenever the cursor hovered over it previously, but recently stopped and now only changes color when it is selected/clicked.

I'm very new to html and css so I know my syntax or method of positioning my elements/divs may be poor.
But if there are any tips or guidance on what I should do to fix this problem, that would be great.

Comment: And where is the HTML?

Comment: sorry I didn't realize html was a potential factor

Comment: Post it please to let us help you.

Comment: `<h2 class="bannerpromo2">` overlays your menu. Use the right-click -> inspect functionality of your browser

Comment: oh it suddenly started working after I inspected the element. Is that some kind of trigger to reset the code or something?

Comment: Also, is there any way to apply the same hover mechanism to my 'subscribebannertext'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the div with class `bannerpromo2` is getting in front of the menu, blocking hover and clicks.

As for the strange behavior you are getting when "inspecting", there is no magic there. Since bannerpromo2 is positioned relative to the bottom (it has `bottom: 470px;`), the position could be changing when you "inspect" it, because the developer panel opens from the bottom of your browser window, thus changing the bottom property of bannerpromo2.

If you want to see all of that in play, give `bannerpromo2` a background color:

```
.bannerpromo2 {
  background-color: green;
  /* ...other props */
}
```